# Trying to send a Transaction to the Star Atlas marketplace using gmClientService which adds a PubKey and won't let me sign

Tags: web3.js

I've been trying for a week to pass a sell order to the Star Atlas marketplace using their Factory package, and it won't seem to work using the snippet provided by the API

```
const orderTx = await gmClientService.getInitializeOrderTransaction(
  connection,
  orderCreator,
  itemMint, 
  quoteMint,
  quantity,
  price,
  programId,
  orderSide,
);

const secKey = new Uint8Array(MyWalletService.wallet.secretKey)
const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secKey)

//console.log(MyWalletService.wallet)

// console.log(JSON.stringify(orderTx.transaction))

const transactionId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  orderTx.transaction,
  [wallet]
);
```

(Everything is properly initialized beforehand)

That throws "Error: Signature verification failed.
Missing signature for public key [`6QmYchjMwWVffGVt5UoApLYVin3Pto9W1KKm9K2Krfkm`]."
That PubKey isn't something I provided and will change when I re-run my script, has anyone some advice on how I can fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a total guess without looking at their source code, but I imagine that `orderCreator` is supposed to sign the transaction too.

Only `wallet` is signing the transaction currently, but it doesn't seem like it's referenced at all when creating the transaction, so maybe `wallet.publicKey` should be the `orderCreator`?

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your response
I haven't put the variable initialization because those contain sensitive data, but orderCreator is aldready initialized as Pubkey(wallet.publicKey)

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, you might need to examine the instructions in your transaction to see what keys are expected to sign. From what you've shown, only `orderCreator` should need to sign